# Qt: Remove multiple rows from QAbstractListModel

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractlistmodel

Is there a way to remove multiple rows, which are not consecutive, efficiently from a QAbstractListModel? Inefficient example:

```
// Single row removal
void remove (int idx) {
    beginRemoveRows (noParent (), idx, idx);
    // internal remove
    endRemoveRows ();
}

// Remove each row by calling beginRemoveRows multiple times
void removeMultiple (const QList<QObject*> &items) {
    foreach (auto item, items)
    {
        int idx = findIndexInternal(item);
        beginRemoveRows (noParent (), idx, idx);
        // internal remove
        endRemoveRows ();
    }
}
```

Regards,

Comment: What does "efficient" mean? You understand that with Model/View you can control what a remove operation does, and hence you can queue remove operations, right?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist he still has to begin/end-remove individually. Alternative: call reset(), but that forgets about selection, current-item (focus) and others in the view. Personally I would not worry too much. If recomputations in the view are very expensive, they can make use of zero-interval timers (see delayed-layout timer in abstract-item-view).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That has nothing to do with efficiency. There's no efficiency problem when doing consecutive removes from the GUI. It's not slower than some other option, for example. It's a GUI! It's not like the human eye requires things to be faster.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist if QAbstractItemModel had a `disableUpdates` or begin/endBatch function, you could very well optimize such repeated operations. I don't understand "It's a GUI It's not like ..." and also "There's no efficiency problem" - I don't know how you wanna know. I have had efficiency problems with item views in the past.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist It's an error to dismiss concerns about efficiency without knowing how many items are in the list.  e.g. if the list has 10 million items in it, then removing 2 million non-consecutive items could well take a long time, even by human-eye standards.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I disagree. The GUI is not showing 10M elements. The *model* has 10M elements. That's a huge distinction. The view shows at best 100 elements? Maybe a little more? That's nothing on any modern machine.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist at least in Qt4.8, every time I inserted a few rows into a model at the end (using begin/endinsertrows), QTableView actually iterated over all existing rows to check something. That made it unusable for me, since the model contained a few hundred-million items.  I expect nothing less to happen in his case. Except if Qt5 fixed this behavior. But in any case, your comment shows that you can't simply make reasonable assumptions without checking the code first.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist i see that in Qt5, QHeaderView::sectionsInserted will not iterate over all sections anymore (Qt4 did create a new section, when the sections inserted were at the end.. I did never understand why...). On the bad side, it will have one item per section (not grouping multiple items anymore, as Qt4 did). In rare cases (if the use has sections hidden, or moved, or on layout change), it will still iterate over all sections. And in any case, it will have an item per model-row in a QVector (10M!). Shows again that the distinction you draw is false.

Comment: last comment on this. See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32325 and https://git.qt.io/consulting-usa/qtbase-xcb-rendering/commit/b800d8b94a7861ecf8853621f6556fca186fb5b7 . I ended up with the same workaround that René Keimling mentioned. Some form of automatic paging.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist The time it takes to remove 2 million elements from a 10-million-element model will depend on the efficiency of the model's internal implementation, as well as on the speed of the underlying hardware.  You can assume that the time taken will be trivial, but unless you know how the model is implemented you could well be mistaken.  Note that not every "modern machine" running Qt is a fast desktop PC with gobs of RAM.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner If you're gonna put 10M elements in the list and make your program support removing 2M at a time, then you better queue/chunk the removal of elements so that it doesn't freeze the GUI. All these issues mentioned here in the comments can be resolved by better management of the model-to-view signaling to update. If Qt has a bug, then we say that we're looking for a workaround. This question by itself is meaningless without a context that describes why such an optimization is necessary. A good model/view design shouldn't care.

Answer (score 2):

See [Qt's Model-View reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html):

> This sequence can be used for any structural update in lieu of the
>   more high-level and convenient protected methods. For example, if a
>   model of two million rows needs to have all odd numbered rows removed,
>   that is 1 million discountiguous ranges of 1 element each. It would be
>   possible to use beginRemoveRows and endRemoveRows 1 million times, but
>   that would obviously be inefficient. Instead, this can be signalled as
>   a single layout change which updates all necessary persistent indexes
>   at once.

It seems you can use [layoutAboutToBeChanged()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutAboutToBeChanged) and [layoutChanged()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutChanged) to signal large alterations to the underlying model. I haven't tested this yet, though.

Update: I currently use this architecture and it does the trick. You don't even have to signal row removal/addition, since this is handled by the layout signal.